# Does a magnetic dipole spins in a uniform magnetic field

Tags: magnetic-fields, dipole-moment

Till now I believed that every magnet has a magnetic moment vector associated with it and that if that magnet is put in a uniform magnetic field its magnetic moment vector tries to align itself with the magnetic field vector but I came across a question while studying the chapter magnetism and matter which is as follows

> The magnetic needle has magnetic moment 6.7×10^-2 Am² and moment of inertia = 7.5×10^-6 kgm². It performs 10 complete oscillations in 6.70 seconds. What is the magnitude of the magnetic field?

---

After reading this question I infer that instead of just aligning itself it spins.
Please explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field creates a torque on the dipole if it is not aligned.  This accelerates the dipole.

When it is aligned, torque is zero, but the rotational speed is non-zero.  So it moves past the alignment orientation.  It oscillates the same way a pendulum does.

No, unless it is given extra energy, it would not be expected to spin all the way around. (The same way a pendulum doesn't fly over the pivot unless you give it a push).